# webapi route with controller and action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

Default webapi route - api/{controller}/{id}

In realtime scenrios may require more get and post methods

Is it recommended to change this like default routing - api/{controller}/{action}/{id}

Comment: Usually default values are recommended values. You don't need to change this unless you have special requirements.

Comment: Add one more route: `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: Also `api/{controller}/{controller}/{id}` is non-sense, why do you want to display your `controller` name two times in the URL?

Comment: @Cuong Le: It depends on the needs, but `{action}` is not everytime needed (if use of GET/PUT...). He may want to create your route as a second route or specify `{action}` as not mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually default values are recommended values. You don't need to change this unless you have special requirements.

`api/{controller}/{controller}/{id}` is a non-sense because you don't have to display two times the name of the controller in the URL.

`{action}` is not everytime needed (if use of GET/PUT...). You may want to create `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` as a second route or specify `{action}` in the default route as `UrlParameter.Optional`.

Comment: sorry it's api/{controller}/{action}/{id}